# How to dynamically reattach a jQuery plugin to a DOM element with different settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is the scenerio:

I have a DOM element on a page with a jQuery plugin attached to it:

`$('.flexslider').flexslider(arguments);`

Now I want to dynamically pass different arguments to the `flexslider()` function depending on the width of the client window. This should work on resize. This is a simplified fragment of my code:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (jqUpdateSize() >= 768) {
        arguments = getDesktopSliderSettings();
    } else {
        arguments = getMobileSliderSettings();
    }        
    $('.flexslider').flexslider(arguments);        
});
```

This would not work as the plugin has been initialized before.

I know that it might not be easy once the plugin has been initialized, but one of the workarounds that I thought about was:

1. Cloning the `.flexslider` DOM element and attaching a new plugin
   with different settings to the clone;
2. Replacing the current slider with the the clone.

What would be the best way to re-attach the plugin with appropriate arguments (mobile/desktop)?

Comment: Normally this would be handled via the plugins options handler, or calls to exposed methods. At the very least, a call to it's destroy method (assuming the author included one), and re-instantiating the plugin on your element. Do you have a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: Hi @Ted. The slider in question is [this](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider). It does not have an exposed detach/remove method so I started looking for a workaround.